AWS amplify init then amplify codegen error: "AppSync API was not found in region"
I'm trying to run this demo: https://github.com/SimonHoiberg/saas-template.
I did an "amplify init", which seems to have succeeded (output below).
Then I ran "codegen add -apiId qmnswth6qnfi7bn5hvsvym63ee" using the supposed ApiId it created, and it replies with this error:

"AppSync API was not found in region us-west-1".

Below turned into a "stream of consciousness" of everything I tried.  Let me shorten to two question:

What happens (i.e. why do we need to run) "amplify code gen" with the AppId?

What is an AppSyncID or apiDI, and where can I go in the AWS Console to see if it is there or not?  Is it related to CloudFormation, Cogito, which AWS service, or is it just a Pulumi concept?

I have done "pulumi down" and "pulumi up" a few times on the back-end files.  I'm still seeing deploying somethings to us-west-1, even though I set my profile to one that uses us-west-2, and configured the /resources/pulumi/variables.ts file with us-west-2 as instructed.
I used this to ideally set my region for "pulumi up":



pulumi config set aws:profile NealProfileWest2
 
pulumi config set awsRegion us-west-2


But parts of it always seem to go to us-west-1 for the Cognito identity-pool and userpool and graphQL endpoints.
This is the output of the "amplify init":
C:\GitHub\SimonHoiberg-Saas-Template\saas-template-main\front-end>amplify init
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Enter a name for the project SaasTemplateFrontEnd
The following configuration will be applied:

Project information
| Name: SaasTemplateFrontEnd
| Environment: dev
| Default editor: Visual Studio Code
| App type: javascript
| Javascript framework: react
| Source Directory Path: src
| Distribution Directory Path: build
| Build Command: npm.cmd run-script build
| Start Command: npm.cmd run-script start

? Initialize the project with the above configuration? Yes
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
AWS access credentials can not be found.
? Setup new user No
? accessKeyId:  ********************
? secretAccessKey:  ****************************************
? region:  us-west-1
Adding backend environment dev to AWS Amplify app: d23p9qcvns9l0s

Deployment completed.
Deploying root stack SaasTemplateFrontEnd [ ==========------------------------------ ] 1/4
        amplify-saastemplatefrontend-… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Fri Apr 12 2024 17:
        UnauthRole                     AWS::IAM::Role                 CREATE_COMPLETE                Fri Apr 12 2024 17:
        DeploymentBucket               AWS::S3::Bucket                CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Fri Apr 12 2024 17:
        AuthRole                       AWS::IAM::Role                 CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Fri Apr 12 2024 17:

√ Help improve Amplify CLI by sharing non-sensitive project configurations on failures (y/N) · no

    You can always opt-in by running "amplify configure --share-project-config-on"
Deployment state saved successfully.
√ Initialized provider successfully.
✅ Initialized your environment successfully.
✅ Your project has been successfully initialized and connected to the cloud!
Some next steps:

"amplify status" will show you what you've added already and if it's locally configured or deployed
"amplify add <category>" will allow you to add features like user login or a backend API
"amplify push" will build all your local backend resources and provision it in the cloud
"amplify console" to open the Amplify Console and view your project status
"amplify publish" will build all your local backend and frontend resources (if you have hosting category added) and provision it in the cloud


Pro tip:
Try "amplify add api" to create a backend API and then "amplify push" to deploy everything

The earlier "pulumi up" command gave this output (except I masked out part of the URLs):
Outputs:

appSyncID       : "qmnswth6qnfi7bn5hvsvym63ee"
dynamoID        : "users-96e9688"
graphQLEndpoint : {

GRAPHQL : "https://xxx.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"
REALTIME: "wss://xxx.appsync-realtime-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"
}


identityPoolID  : output
userpoolClientID: output
userpoolID      : output

So following his instructions, I ran this command, and the results follow:
C:\GitHub\SimonHoiberg-Saas-Template\saas-template-main\front-end>amplify codegen add -apiId 'qmnswth6qnfi7bn5hvsvym63ee'
× Getting API details
AppSync API was not found in region us-west-1
? Do you want to choose a different region (Y/n)

When I go to the AWS Console, I can see this in US-WEST-1 (N. California):

and a

However, when I go to Cogito or Lambda (in US-WEST-1) I don't see the anything created by the "pulumi up" of the back-end.  (I thought I saw something in Cogito last week, but cannot find it today.)  I do however see a "Cloudformation" entry related to this project.
I tried "amplify status", "amplify push", and "amplify publish" in my Windows console, with the following results:

So I'm at a loss of what I need to next.
After all the above, I discovered that I didn't change his EU-WEST-1 that was buried in one of the config/source files, even though I set my region on the command line.
After that, I totally deleted the "stack" on Pulumi, reuploaded it with "pulumi up", and then I see everything on US-WEST-1.
But I still get this error:
C:\GitHub\SimonHoiberg-Saas-Template\saas-template-main\front-end>amplify codegen add -apiId 'e3k6yhswrbfs3e5o65sa7vz32y'
× Getting API details
AppSync API was not found in region us-west-2
? Do you want to choose a different region No

NOTE: I deployed the backend to us-west-2, and used us-west-2 when I did the "amplify init" in the last attempt.  I also did an "amplify delete" and started all over to hopefully clean-up any lingering region issues.
Update #1 -
I decided to quit fighting the system, and use US-WEST-1.
So I did "pulumi destroy", changed config file to use US-WEST-1, "pulumi up", got the keys, updated keys in front end config file, and still get the following (except now it says US-WEST-1):
C:\GitHub\SimonHoiberg-Saas-Template\saas-template-main\front-end>amplify codegen add -apiId 'ws4w76tqyjahdhuzricu5676oq'
× Getting API details
AppSync API was not found in region us-west-1
? Do you want to choose a different region No

Update #2:
This page may have a typo (no colon between aws and region), but doc page shows a colon.

1st page: pulumi config set awsregion us-west-2
2nd page: pulumi config set aws:region us-west-2

So I undeployed everything, redeployed everything and same issue as Update #1 above.

I think I have decided to use Vercel and NextJS for this project.  Seems like there is not a lot of community support for aws-amplify and Pulumi; not a single comment to this question in 4 days.
